# Make UIElement visible only under SpotLight

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win2d, xaml-composition

I have an rectangle:

```
<Border x:Name="Elem1" BorderThickness="2" Height="100" Width="200" BorderBrush="Red" />
```

And a Windows.UI.Composition.**SpotLight** moving togehter with pointer:

```
const float LightDistance = 20;
_compositor = Window.Current.Compositor;
_pointLight = _compositor.CreatePointLight();
_pointLight.Color = Colors.White;
_pointLight.Targets.Add(ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(Elem1)); 

PointerMoved += (o, e) => {
    var point = e.GetCurrentPoint(this).Position;
    _pointLight.Offset = new Vector3((float)point.X, (float)point.Y, LightDistance);
};
```

When there is no light over rectagle, it remain black:

[image]

**I would like the rest of the rectangle to be transparent, so only enlightened part will be visible**

I've tried to add transparent AmblientLight, but the aplha channel is ignored.

I guess it could be achieved by `SceneLightingEffect`, but how? :)

Comment: you may use mask instead of spotlight, if it suit your case

Comment: I tried also this but wasn't succesful. Not because it us impossible, but because of my limited knowlegde of uwp I dont know how to create radial gradient mask and move it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special for you :D

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private CompositionSurfaceBrush _maskSurfaceBrush;
    private readonly float _size = 512;

    private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PointerMoved += MainPage_PointerMoved;

        var compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this).Compositor;
        var canvasDevice = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
        var graphicsDevice = CanvasComposition.CreateCompositionGraphicsDevice(compositor, canvasDevice);

        var canvasBitmap = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(canvasDevice, new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/44578.jpg"));

        var sourceDrawingSurface = graphicsDevice.CreateDrawingSurface(new Size(_size, _size), DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized, DirectXAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
        using (var ds = CanvasComposition.CreateDrawingSession(sourceDrawingSurface))
        {
            ds.Clear(Colors.Transparent);
            ds.DrawImage(canvasBitmap);
        }

        var sourceSurfaceBrush = compositor.CreateSurfaceBrush(sourceDrawingSurface);

        var maskRenderTarget = new CanvasRenderTarget(canvasDevice, _size, _size, 96);
        using (var ds = maskRenderTarget.CreateDrawingSession())
        {
            ds.Clear(Colors.Transparent);
            ds.FillCircle(_size / 2, _size / 2, _size / 8, Colors.Black);
        }

        var blur = new GaussianBlurEffect
        {
            BlurAmount = 16,
            Source = maskRenderTarget
        };

        var blurredMaskDrawingSurface = graphicsDevice.CreateDrawingSurface(new Size(_size, _size), DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized, DirectXAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
        using (var ds = CanvasComposition.CreateDrawingSession(blurredMaskDrawingSurface))
        {
            ds.Clear(Colors.Transparent);
            ds.DrawImage(blur);
        }

        _maskSurfaceBrush = compositor.CreateSurfaceBrush(blurredMaskDrawingSurface);

        var composite = new CompositeEffect
        {
            Sources = { new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("source"), new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("mask") },
            Mode = CanvasComposite.DestinationAtop
        };

        var effectFactory = compositor.CreateEffectFactory(composite);
        var fxBrush = effectFactory.CreateBrush();
        fxBrush.SetSourceParameter("source", sourceSurfaceBrush);
        fxBrush.SetSourceParameter("mask", _maskSurfaceBrush);

        var sprite = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
        sprite.Size = new Vector2(_size, _size);
        sprite.Brush = fxBrush;

        ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(this, sprite);
    }

    private void MainPage_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var position = e.GetCurrentPoint(this).Position.ToVector2();

        _maskSurfaceBrush.Offset = position - new Vector2(_size / 2, _size / 2);
    }
```

Works better than ever!